# All possible combinations of strings from char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, combinations

I'm having a school project for Java and I'm assigned too. Now I'm having an issue with a part of the project which I can't figure out.
The application must generate all possible word combinations (can be verified via a dictionary) from a two-dimensional char array (char[][] board). The board is dynamic as the user can choose the scale: 4x4, 5x5, 4x5, 5x4, 4x6, ... So I guess a nested loop wouldn't be approriate here, correct me if I'm wrong. Words must be generated horizontally, verticaly and diagonally. Example of a 4x4 board:

| u | a | u | s |

| n | n | i | i |

| a | o | e | b |

| e | u | e | z |

```
    Code was completely wrong.
```

Another idea may be to brute force every possible path on the board and then try those saved paths to verify whether it's a word or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "generate words on the board"? What is your input, and what it the desired output?

Comment: The application generates a board on a random base (with random chars) and must then find all possible words on the board in multiple directions (horizontally, vertically and diagonally) and may not visit a character twice.

Comment: What does "in multiple directions" mean? Can a single word use multiple directions, i.e. does the word have to be in a straight line or may it curve across the board?

Comment: All possible directions, once the cursor (let's say) selects a character from there on, it can go jump to all its neighboors and so on ... The actual directions it can go to are saved in the HashMap<Point, Point[]> neighbouringCoords;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is:

```
for each path on the board
    if corresponding word in dictionary
        print it
```

To find all paths, you could adapt any [graph traversal algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).

Now this will be really slow, because there are a great many paths of a board that size (for a board with n cells, we can have at most `n * 4 ^ (n - 1)` paths, so for a 5 by 5 board, you'd have something like 25 * 2 ^ 50 ~= 10^16 paths.

One way to improve on this is to interleave traversing the graph and checking the dictionary, aborting if the current path's word is not a prefix of a dictionary word:

```
class Board {

    char[][] ch;
    boolean[][] visited;

    Trie dictionary;

    void find() {
        StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < maxx; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < maxy; y++) {
                walk(x, y, prefix);
            }
        }
     }

    void walk(int x, int y, StringBuilder prefix) {
        if (!visited[x][y]) {
            visited[x][y] = true;
            prefix.append(ch[x][y]);

            if (dictionary.hasPrefix(prefix)) {
                if (dictionary.contains(prefix)) {
                    System.out.println(prefix);
                }

                int firstX = Math.max(0, x - 1);
                int lastX = Math.min(maxx, x + 1);
                int firstY = Math.max(0, y - 1);
                int lastY = Math.min(maxy, y + 1);
                for (int ax = firstX; ax <= lastX; ax++) {
                    for (int ay = firstY; ay <= lastY; ay++) {
                        walk(ax, ay, prefix);
                    }
                }
            }

            prefix.setLength(prefix.length() - 1);
            visited[x][y] = false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the method walk invokes itself. This technique is known as [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

That leaves the matter of finding a data structure for the dictionary that supports efficient prefix queries. The best such data structure is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Alas, the JDK does not contain an implementation, but fortunately, writing one isn't hard.

Note: The code in this answer has not been tested.

Comment: I now have a somewhat similiar recursive method: private void findWord(Woord woord, int positionInWord, Point currentPosition, HashSet<Point> visited, StringBuilder currentWoord) { ... } and it works, but gives some unusual result at times, like characters which are not connected etc ...

Answer (score 0):

A fairly straightforward way of conceptualizing this is to apply a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) approach to each position (or depth-first, depending upon which tweaks you might later want to make).  This would give you all possible letter combinations, up to a level of characters equal to the max depth of the search.  Depending on your requirements, such as the longest allowed word, max running time, and if a dictionary is provided via a data structure or file, this may be the key part.

Or, you may need to optimize quite a bit more.  If so, consider how you might expedite either a BFS or DFS.  What if you did a DFS, but knew three characters in that no word starts with "zzz"?  You could shave a lot of time off by not having to traverse all conceivable orderings.  To look words up effectively, you might need to make further adjustments.  But I'd start with Java's built-in functionality (String.startsWith() comes to mind in this instance), measure performance (perhaps with a limited max word length), and then optimize when and where it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Start by turning rows , columns and diagonals to Strings, using a simple repetitive method. Then , I would turn it into a StringBuilder or in order to check which words are real and eliminate those which aren't directly from the StringBuilder. then , just print it to a String.There are a lot of useful tools to eliminate or replace words in java.